# How to log a cronjob?

Tags: bash, logs, macintosh

I have this Main script:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Array of Mac hostnames separated by spaces
my_macs=( Mac111 Mac121 Mac122 Mac123 Mac124 Mac125 Mac126 Mac127 Mac128 Mac129 )

#Steps through each hostname and issues SSH command to that host
#Loops through the elements of the Array

for n in "${my_macs[@]}"
do
    # -q quiet
    # -c nb of pings to perform

    ping -q -c3 "${n}" > /dev/null

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        ssh admusr@"${n}" 'sudo bash -s' < ./documents/ShutdownUPTIME.sh
    else
        echo "${n} is not available"
    fi

done

exit 0
```

The main script runs a seperate script. This is ShutdownUPTIME.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
BOOT_TIME=$(sysctl -n kern.boottime | sed -e 's/.* sec = \([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
CURR_TIME=$(date +%s)
MAX_UPDAYS=1 #Days

DAYS_UP=$(( ( $CURR_TIME - $BOOT_TIME) / 86400 ))
if [ $DAYS_UP -ge ${MAX_UPDAYS} ];then
    echo Mac is going to shutdown 
    sudo shutdown -h now
else
        echo No shutdown for Mac needed
fi
```

Now I have 2 problems:

First problem:

I made a cronjob (with `crontab -e`: `30 23 * * * ./documents/shutdownsimple.sh`). I want to log this cronjob, either through the script or the cronjob itself (I want to know when it runs and what exactly it does; for more information look at the echo in the scripts), how can I do that?

Second problem:

If I log the script it will just say `Mac is going to shutdown` but I want it to say `Mac111 is going to shutdown` or `No need to shutdown Mac125`. The names do not show though, any idea how I can accomplish that?

If you find any mistakes, feel free to edit my post, english is not my first language

Comment: At the top of my main script you can see the array with different Mac names. Theses should be filled in instead of only "Mac"

Comment: cron sends email about every action as default. no need for logging twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly to get the script to show the name of the machine two things:
a) Change the way you remotely execute the script to run it directly on the remote host.  This requires that you copy the script to the remote machine.  I like to store my personal utility scripts in a directory called "do" in my home directory, so I would have it as
`~/do/ShutdownUPTIME.sh`

Now change the line which reads
`ssh admusr@"${n}" 'sudo bash -s' < ./documents/ShutdownUPTIME.sh`

to this:
`ssh admusr@"${n}" sudo do/ShutdownUPTIME.sh $n`

Basically you are passing $n, the name of the machine, to it as parameter.

b) Then change the ShutdownUPTIME.sh script to use the passed argument.  Where you have `Mac` put `$MACNAME`.  Near the start of the script add the line
`MACNAME=$1`

The script will now look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
MACNAME=$1
BOOT_TIME=$(sysctl -n kern.boottime | sed -e 's/.* sec = \([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
CURR_TIME=$(date +%s)
MAX_UPDAYS=1 #Days

DAYS_UP=$(( ( $CURR_TIME - $BOOT_TIME) / 86400 ))
if [ $DAYS_UP -ge ${MAX_UPDAYS} ];then
    echo Notice: $MACNAME is going to shutdown 
    sudo shutdown -h now
else
        echo Info: No shutdown for $MACNAME needed
fi
```

I also added "Notice" and "Info" to the output commands to give them some level of importance - this helps with later log filtering.

For bonus make the script handle the situation where you did not supply a Mac Name by having a default value.  For example the MACNAME value assignment becomes

`MACNAME=${1:-$(hostname)}`

About logging: Cron will send you an email with the output of every job, but this can be really inconvenient.  The simplest solution is to redirect the output of the commands to a local log file.

For this simply add the redirection on the "done" line of the loop, so it becomes

`done | tee -a $LOGFILE 2>&1`

And this of course requires you to set up a name in the LOGFILE variable earlier in the script, so add a line like this near the start:
`LOGFILE=/var/log/refreshing.log`
(Note: Specify a path to a file which you have permission to write to)

In addition you may want to regularly add a timestamp to this log, so just before the loop add the line
`echo Running Refresh at $(date) | tee -a $LOGILFE`

Logging output from the cron command means your logging only happens when your script is executed from cron.  Making the script manage it's own logging is therefore preferred.  I changed the script to use `tee` in stead of redirection so that when you run it on the command line you can still see the output.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works perfectly exactly how I imagined it
Edit>

Comment: Edit: it doesn't log properly, I apparently don't have permission to write on that file.... I checked the privileges and it says for everyone Read&Write.

Comment: You can do one of two things.  Change the log file destination to a path where you do have permissions to write, or else create the log file (as root) and grant your user write access to the file.